# jwtUtils.getUserId is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently encountering a problem when retrieving a getUserId function present in an Auth.js file (file where I manage my authentication token generation management).

I can't retrieve this function from my User controllers because it tells me that it's not a function... Can you help me? Thanks a lot !

My fonction getUserId from my file userCtrl :

```js
exports.getUserProfile = (req, res) => {
    let headerAuth = req.headers['authorization'];
    let userId = jwtUtils.getUserId(headerAuth);

    if (userId < 0)
        return res.status(400).json({ 'error': 'wrong token' });

    models.User.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'email', 'username', 'bio'],
        where: { id: userId }
    }).then((user) => {
        if (user) {
            res.status(201).json(user);
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({ 'error': 'user not found' });
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ 'error': 'cannot fetch user' });
    });
}
```

My file Auth.js :

```js
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config();

const JWT_SIGN_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SIGN_SECRET

module.exports = {
    generateTokenForUser: (userdata) => {
        return jwt.sign({
            userId: userdata.userId,
            isAdmin: userdata.isAdmin
        },
            JWT_SIGN_SECRET,
            {
                expiresIn: '1h'
            })
    }
},
    parseAuthorization = (authorization) => {
        return (authorization != nuill) ? authorization.replace('bearer', '') : null;
    },
    getUserId = (authorization) => {
        let userId = -1;
        let token = module.exports.parseAuthorization(authorization);
        if (token != null) {
            try {
                let jwtToken = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SIGN_SECRET);
                if (jwtToken != null)
                    userId = jwtToken.userId;
            } catch (err) { }
        }
        return userId;
    }
```

My error :

```
TypeError: jwtUtils.getUserId is not a function
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\P7\P7\Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\P7\P7\Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\P7\P7\Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\P7\P7\Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\P7\P7\Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\P7\P7\Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
at router (C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\P7\P7\Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me; go into your authorization function and remove Bearer like this:

```
parseAuthorization: (authorization)=>{return (authorization !=null) ?authorization.replace('',''):null;},
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not exporting the last two functions. Here I just removed parseAuthorization function because I have some doubts about it. Maybe this will solve your issue. If not work let me know.

```
module.exports = {
    generateTokenForUser: (userdata) => {
        return jwt.sign({
            userId: userdata.userId,
            isAdmin: userdata.isAdmin
        },
            JWT_SIGN_SECRET,
            {
                expiresIn: '1h'
            })
    },
    getUserId : (authorization) => {
        let userId = -1;
        let token = authorization? authorization.replace('bearer', 
       ''):'';
        if (token != null) {
            try {
                let jwtToken = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SIGN_SECRET);
                if (jwtToken != null)
                    userId = jwtToken.userId;
            } catch (err) { }
        }
        return userId;
    }
}
```